# Splitting this Cells into Multiple Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to split some cells into multiple rows. I currently am trying to break the cells up into column G (see pic below and) have all the same data in the lines below, with just the cells being split into multiple rows. Is this possible to be done?

Starting here:
[image]

and finishing with this:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible? Sure. Please include your attempt in your question and explain where you ran into trouble.

Comment: https://trumpexcel.com/split-multiple-lines/

Comment: Besides this you can use VBA/macro to do the same

Comment: Use PowerQuery for this type of stuff

Answer (score 0):

If macro function is ok, here is sample code

```
Sub Split()
  Dim meargedline As String
  Dim rowNumber As Integer
  rowNumber = 2
  Dim splitData

  For i = 2 To 4
   meargedline = Cells(i, 3)
   splitData = VBA.Split(meargedline, Chr(10))

   For j = LBound(splitData, 1) To UBound(splitData, 1)
    Cells(j + rowNumber, 4) = Cells(i, 1)
    Cells(j + rowNumber, 5) = Cells(i, 2)
    Cells(j + rowNumber, 6) = splitData(j)
   Next j
   rowNumber = rowNumber + UBound(splitData, 1) + 1
Next i
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will do a basic loop through and generate an output. Note the constants and make sure you specify for your workbook. [You can see an example of it here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9g4ts9GTtvNdZkSjmyg?e=NaBNUm).

```
Sub runSplitter()
Const topRightCellAddress = "E20"
Const startCellToSetValues = "A1" 'where new rows will be placed
Const sheetOneName = "Start" 'make sure these match"
Const sheetTwoName = "Output"
Const codeOfLineSplitter = 10 'asci code line splitter


Dim firstSheet As Worksheet, secondSheet As Worksheet
    Set firstSheet = Sheets(sheetOneName)
    Set secondSheet = Sheets(sheetTwoName)

Dim aCell As Range
    Set aCell = firstSheet.Range(topRightCellAddress)

Dim aRR() As String
Dim r As Long
Do While Not IsEmpty(aCell)
    aRR = Split(aCell.Value2, Chr(codeOfLineSplitter), -1)
    
    Dim i As Long
    With secondSheet.Range(startCellToSetValues)
    For i = LBound(aRR) To UBound(aRR)
        
        .Offset(r, 0).Value2 = aCell.Offset(0, -2).Value2
        .Offset(r, 1).Value2 = aCell.Offset(0, -1).Value2
        .Offset(r, 2).Value2 = aRR(i)
        r = r + 1
    Next i
    
    End With
    
    Set aCell = aCell.Offset(1, 0)
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use power query to achieve the target you want. Click here for reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJ6y2anloW4.

Comment: use power query to do the split to multiple rows, then add a column. Finally load to the worksheet.